# AJAX Post suddenly stopped working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I think I changed something, and now it's not working. I have tried everything. Commenting out everything, but it's late so I am probably making stupid mistakes. Here it is:

```
// Show All Work on Load
function showAllWorkOnLoad() {
var thePostData = "filter=allwork";
var inner = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
alert(inner);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://justtwobros.com/get_work.php",
    data: thePostData,
    success: function(theRetrievedData) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = theRetrievedData;
        $("#content").fadeIn(20);
        focusButtonAllWork();

        var count = 0;
        $("#content").find('.work_thumbnail_wrapper').each(function() {
            count++;
            var timeWait = (count * 100) + 500;
            var theId = $(this).attr('id');  
            var theIdDone = "#" + theId;
            setTimeout(function(){$(theIdDone).fadeIn(300);},timeWait);
        }); 

    }
});
}
```

If you want a link, here it is: http://justtwobros.com

Nothing is showing up in the side (it calls this javascript function to get results from a php file, then put it in, then fade in the sections. I know it's messing up here because I just put text in the PHP file and it still didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: try to alert any message inside success function

Comment: Tried that... Nothing showed up...

Comment: means some error occurs while returning data from the post method

Comment: Then add `error` callback, and see what you get there (it seems that the request is not that `success`ful)

Comment: The error my browser is detecting seems to involve the loading of jQuery itself. I'd definitely make a point of stripping out the second jQuery import (you're loading both version 1.6.1 and 1.2.2)

Comment: @jerluc: Removed the earlier version, did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other issue I see is that you are loading both jQuery and Prototype.

Prototype uses a $ object just as jQuery does. Since you are loading Prototype second, it's definition of the $ object is overwriting jQuery's, resulting in an error along the lines of ".ajax() not defined for object $".

Remove Prototype.js and it should work.

Comment: That little booger. Spent hours pulling my hair out going to and from my PHP and javascript... Thanks!

Comment: But I need prototype.js for a lightbox. How do I incorporate it, but not have it mess it up like it did before? I tried putting it before, but it still didn't work.

Comment: There are plenty of jQuery-friendly alternatives to lightbox. However, there is this jQuery version here..http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: Awesome. I am actually liking the look of this one better!

Comment: Good to hear, two birds with half a stone I'd say

Answer (score 2):

Activate Firebug's Console tab on http://justtwobros.com and you'll see the error "$.ajax is not a function"

The page imports jQuery 1.6.1 and then imports jQuery 1.2.2 which overwrites the modern jQuery object with an older version. Try removing jQuery 1.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

you are changing innerHtml of content here with `asdfasdf`

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "asdfasdf";
```

and then you are trying to get --`.work_thumbnail_wrapper` inside `content`, which is of-course not there..

```
 $("#content").find('.work_thumbnail_wrapper').each(function() {
```

so i think this might be a cause...

Comment: That was for a test. sorry. Going to change it in my question. I don't even get a success message!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing Prototype.js, you are able to use jQuery.ajax(), instead of $.ajax()

This should resolve the issue of both jQuery & Prototype using the $ syntax.

ex:
    $.('#myDiv');
    jQuery.('#myDiv');
    // Both are valid

There is also a function called: jQuery.noConflict(), you can read more about it here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/